# Solving for $z$ given 3 constraints: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[z^4]=1/2$ , $z\bar{z}+2|z|-3=0$, $\arg z \leq \frac{\pi}{4}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> > Let $z$ be a complex number satisfying
>
> $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[z^4]=\frac{1}{2}$$
>
> $$z\bar{z}+2|z|-3=0$$
>
> $$\arg z \leq \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
>
> Find $z$

As a side note this is the same as this question here: [Finding complex number defined by 3 equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404897/finding-complex-number-defined-by-3-equations?rq=1) , but I'm looking for a way to finish it using my approach.

---

I'm going to let $z = x+iy$ and attempt to solve for $x$ and $y$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[z^4]=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[(x+iy)^4]=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2 +i(4x^3y-4xy^3)]=\frac{1}{2}$$

Considering real only

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re[x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2]=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$

---

Now with the second equation

$$z\bar{z}+2|z|-3=0$$

$$ (x+iy)(x-iy) + 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 3 = 0 $$

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 3 = 0 $$

---

I will worry about the argument after I solve for $x$ and $y$.

---

I now have $2$ equations:

$$ x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 3 = 0 $$

Working on the second one

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 3 = 0 $$

Let $x^2+y^2$ $=$ $p$

$$ p + 2\sqrt{p} - 3 = 0 $$

$$ (\sqrt{p}-1)(\sqrt{p}+3) = 0 $$

$$ \sqrt{p} = 1 , \sqrt{p} \neq -3 $$

$$ x^2+y^2 =1 $$

Squaring both sides

$$ x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 = 1 $$

$$ x^4 + y^4 = 1-2x^2y^2 $$

Subbing this into the first equation

$$ x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ 1-2x^2y^2-6x^2y^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \frac{1}{2} = 8x^2y^2 $$

$$ \frac{1}{16} = x^2y^2 $$

$$ y^2 = \frac{1}{16x^2} $$

Subbing this into

$$ x^2+\frac{1}{16x^2} =1 $$

$$ x^4 - x^2 + \frac{1}{16} = 0 $$

$$ x^2 = \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}  , x^2 = \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

$$ x = ± \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} , x= ± \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} $$

$$ y = ± \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} , y= ± \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

Now I am stuck which set is correct to represent $z=x+iy$?

Comment: You didn't take the 3rd condition did you? From that you get only one set.

Comment: What is your range for $\arg$? $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: any reason not to use polar form?

Comment: @benji I wanted to see if I could brute force through it algebraically :)

Answer (score 1):

The third condition gives you - Both $x$ and $y$ are positive and $x>y$

So, from your set of answers(assuming they are right), the answer would be

$x=\frac{\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2}{4}$
$y=\frac{\sqrt 6-\sqrt 2}{4}$